# Make vscode explorer follow the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is there a way to make vscode explorer follow the terminal? Mobaxterm has such capability. I usually ssh into a remote system and such a feature would be very desirable. Currently, I cd to a directory, then copy and paste the path to "Open Folder" in vscode which takes some time.

I know clt+click on the path in the terminal opens a new vscode window, but that is not very helpful. I am interested explorer automatically follow the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the terminal command `code . --reuse-window` to open the folder you are currently in.

Comment: this is not an answer to the OP's question, though this is a neet command it does not allow the VS navigator follow the CD commands from the VS terminal